# React Native variables between JavaScript classes

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to set up a navigation action using react-navigation but I am having trouble since I am using a FlatList and a Pure Component to render the items in the list. The list is rendering fine but when I try to add an onPress function to the TouchableHighlight I cannot call the normal navigate function because it does not know what the variable navigate means. I would like to keep the separate file for the Pure Component instead of moving it into the other class if possible.

Pure Component:

```
export default class Lot extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => navigate('LotView')}
            >
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 150, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <View>
                        {this.props.active && (<Image source={images[this.props.index]} style={[styles.images]} />)}
                    </View>

                 </View>

            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
}
```

The following are in my App.js class.

FlatList

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.lots}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Lot {...item} />}
/>
```

Navigation screens

```
export const MyApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    LotView: { screen: LotView },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot should be dummy component (should not have any external access)

```
export default class Lot extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={this.props.onPress} // <== CHANGED
            >
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 150, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <View>
                        {this.props.active && (<Image source={images[this.props.index]} style={[styles.images]} />)}
                    </View>

                 </View>

            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
}
```

HomeScreen

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.lots}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Lot {...item} onPress={() => this.props.navigate('LotView')} />} //<== CHANGED
/>
```